# What on earth is the relationship between Git and Git workflow?

Tags: git, version-control, git-flow, git-workflow

I'm a bit confused about these two terms `git` & `gitflow`.

I know that Git is one of the version control systems, and git workflow is something about 'master/develop/feature/release/hotfix branches'.
But what on earth is the relationship between these two and what's the difference?

and are 'gitflow' & 'git workflow' the same?

Comment: This analogy is imperfect, but think of Git as a workshop full of tools (for some task, whether that's carpentry, or textile weaving, or whatever) and Git-flow as a set of procedures for *using* the tools: when to use which one, what kind of wood or fabric to use, and so on. The instructions make no sense unless you have the tool-set. There are other ways to use the tool-set. If you get your work done, your way is as good as any other—at least, until you accidentally saw off your arm and see *why* the instructions say "always turn off the bandsaw" or whatever.

Comment: In this analogy, there may be some instructions that exist *only* because the author of the instruction believes those are right: they don't actually help with getting work done, or increase safety, or whatever. If your boss says you must follow those instructions, though, then you must follow them anyway. Otherwise, just think of them as guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since git is very flexible and not enforcing or limiting you to use and workflow, the community have tried to define and recommend a different workflow which should be used for developing with git

First read this article: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow which will answer most of your questions.

regarding `gitflow` - it's a methodology/flow introduced by Vincent Driessen back in 2010.

Here is the full article he wrote and described his idea, and the good part of it is that he added Open Source scripting for almost everything he described there and today git-flow is the most commonly used  workflow

https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Comment: Hi I know what gitflow and git are, just confused about the relationship between them.